# How do you write all user emails from a Django user database to a text file?

Tags: django, shell, export

Using shell commands, what is the quickest way to export all user email addresses from a Django database into a text document?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser The interface actually suggests this very action, Matthew. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. But if you have a better answer, please feel free to add your idea and I'll choose it if it beats my own.

Comment: No, just found it curious. It's definitely sanctioned but just had yet to see someone do it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you store user email addresses on the User.email field:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

handle = open('emails.txt', 'w+')
for user in User.objects.all():
    handle.write(user.email+'\n')
handle.close()
```

The file, `emails.txt` will likely be in the project root for your django project.